# how to identify which tables in oracle got inserted / updated / deleted

Tags: oracle

i have inherited a third party  code base 
i would like to find which tables are inserted / updated / deleted from on a particular screen operation

In oracle XE - is there a way like listeners which will tell me the sql which got triggered ?

I am only interested in inserts / updates / deletes and not selects

any ideas ?

Comment: There are plenty of auditing capabilities in Oracle, but not sure if they are available in the XE version, probably not.  If you have a small number of tables, you can write your own triggers, but that will be cumbersome if there is a lot of them.  You did not specify what framework the app is written in, but if it uses something like ODBC/JDBC/ADO.Net for data access, they have their own tracing capabilities.

Comment: thanks - this uses hibernate